# image stack display in matlab using a slider

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, slider, stack

I have a 3 dimension matrix of data (a stack of images across a dimension, time for example.
I want to display an image, and have a slider below to navigate across the images.

I wrote a piece of code which works, but it's bulky and kinda ugly I think...I want to write a clean function and so I would like to know if anyone know of a cleaner, nicer way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
interv = [min max]; % interval for image visualization

imagesc(Temps_visu,X*100,squeeze(X,Y,MyMatrix(:,:,1)),interv);

title('My Title');
xlabel('X (cm)');
ylabel('Y (cm)');

pos = get(gca,'position');
% slider position
Newpos = [pos(1) pos(2)-0.1 pos(3) 0.05];

pp = 1;
% callback slider
S = ['pp=floor(get(gcbo,''value''));imagesc(Temps_visu,X*100,squeeze(X,Y,MyMatrix(:,:,1)),interv));' ...
    'set_axes_elasto;title(''My Title'');disp(pp);'];

Mz = size(MyMatrix,3);

% Creating Uicontrol
h = uicontrol('style','slider',...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position',Newpos,...
    'callback',S,...
    'min',1,'max',Mz,...
    'value',pp,...
    'sliderstep',[1/(Mz-1) 10/(Mz-1)]);
```

Comment: So @Gordon Freeman did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it using a listener object for smooth visualization of your stack. I made up a dummy stack using grayscale variations of the same image (i.e. only 4 frames) but the principle will be the same for your application. Notice that I use `imshow` to display the images, but using `imagesc` as you do won't cause any problem.

The code is commented so hopefully this is clear enough. If not please don't hesitate to ask for help!

Code:

```
function SliderDemo
clc
clear all

NumFrames = 4; %// Check below for dummy 4D matrix/image sequence
hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','normalized');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','normalized','Position',[.2 .2 .6 .6]);

%// Create slider and listener object for smooth visualization
handles.SliderFrame = uicontrol('Style','slider','Position',[60 20 400 50],'Min',1,'Max',NumFrames,'Value',1,'SliderStep',[1/NumFrames 2/NumFrames],'Callback',@XSliderCallback);
handles.SliderxListener = addlistener(handles.SliderFrame,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) XListenerCallBack);

handles.Text1 = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[180 420 60 30],'String','Current frame');
handles.Edit1 = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[250 420 100 30],'String','1');

%// Create dummy image sequence, here 4D sequence of grayscale images.
MyImage = imread('peppers.png');

MyMatrix = cat(4,rgb2gray(MyImage),MyImage(:,:,1),MyImage(:,:,2),MyImage(:,:,3));

%// Use setappdata to store the image stack and in callbacks, use getappdata to retrieve it and use it. Check the docs for the calling syntax.

setappdata(hFig,'MyMatrix',MyMatrix); %// You could use %//setappdata(0,'MyMatrix',MyMatrix) to store in the base workspace. 

%// Display 1st frame
imshow(MyMatrix(:,:,:,1))

%// IMPORTANT. Update handles structure.
guidata(hFig,handles);

%// Listener callback, executed when you drag the slider.

    function XListenerCallBack

        %// Retrieve handles structure. Used to let MATLAB recognize the
        %// edit box, slider and all UI components.
        handles = guidata(gcf);

%// Here retrieve MyMatrix using getappdata.
MyMatrix = getappdata(hFig,'MyMatrix');

        %// Get current frame
        CurrentFrame = round((get(handles.SliderFrame,'Value')));
        set(handles.Edit1,'String',num2str(CurrentFrame));

        %// Display appropriate frame.
        imshow(MyMatrix(:,:,:,CurrentFrame),'Parent',handles.axes1);

        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end


%// Slider callback; executed when the slider is release or you press
%// the arrows.
    function XSliderCallback(~,~)

        handles = guidata(gcf);

%// Here retrieve MyMatrix using getappdata.
    MyMatrix = getappdata(hFig,'MyMatrix');

        CurrentFrame = round((get(handles.SliderFrame,'Value')));
        set(handles.Edit1,'String',num2str(CurrentFrame));

        imshow(MyMatrix(:,:,:,CurrentFrame),'Parent',handles.axes1);

        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end

end
```

The figure looks like this:

## [image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very nice example. 2 remarks though. You could add `'SliderStep',[1/NumFrames 2/NumFrames]` in the slider definition (but that's just a comfort thing). The other remark is that it is generally recommended to keep the `guidata` structure for `handles` only. Heavier data sets (like all your images frames etc...) are better placed in their own variable/structure with `setappdata`/`getappdata`. This way matlab doesn't need to pass your heavy data set in the subfunction workspace every time you call `guidata` just to get the handle of a single uicontrol.